# Resizing an EMF image in XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to resize an `EMF` image after inserting it into an `XSSFWorkbook`.
There is support resizing `PNG`, `JPEG` and `DIB` images.

```
private void addNormalFigure(XSSFSheet sheet, byte[] imgData){
    XSSFWorkbook w = sheet.getWorkbook();
    int picIdx = w.addPicture(imgData, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF);
    CreationHelper helper = w.getCreationHelper();
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
    // Column : A
    anchor.setCol1(0);
    // Row : 4
    anchor.setRow1(4);
    Picture pic = drawing.createPicture(anchor, picIdx);
    double height = 2.0;
    double width = 2.0;
    // sets the anchor.col2 to 0 and anchor.row2 to 0
    pic.getImageDimension().setSize(inchToPixel(width), inchToPixel(height));
    // pic.resize(); -> this too sets the anchor.col2 to 0 and anchor.row2 to 0
}

private double inchToPixel(double in) {
    return in * 96.0;
}
```

Is there any way we can **workaround** this problem?

Comment: the Dimension object which you get from `Picture.getImageDimension()` can't be used to change the size, i.e. `setSize(...)` is futile. You need to call `Picture.resize(double scaleX, double scaleY)`. If you look at `XSSFPicture.resize(double scaleX, double scaleY)` you see that only DX2/DY2 is changed. So if your comment is correct, `XSSFPicture.getPreferredSize(scaleX,scaleY)` calculates wrong and it might be an issue of column width or row height - which you can easily find out by debugging that method ...

Comment: I debugged the `XSSFPicture.getPreferredSize(scaleX,scaleY)`. The problem lies in [ImageUtils.getImageDimension(InputStream,int)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_0_0/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/ImageUtils.java?revision=1885418&view=markup#l64) which clearly specifies that there is no support  for `EMF` (while `EMF` is a predominant image format for `MS Office Suite`).

Comment: `Apache poi` does not provide to get image dimensions from `Picture` of type `Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF`. But it provides `org.apache.poi.hemf.usermodel.HemfPicture`. So `HemfPicture hemfPicture = new HemfPicture(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgData)); System.out.println(hemfPicture.getSize());` will print the correct dimensions. But then it lacks a possibility to set those dimensions to the anchor. There is a method `scaleCell` in `org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils` but not public accessible.

Comment: @AxelRichter I tried accessing [HemfPicture](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hemf/usermodel/HemfPicture.html). However, I am unable to access it since it is annotated `@Internal`. Any way I can access an `internal` class?

Comment: Not clear where exactly is your problem. I have no problem to `import org.apache.poi.hemf.usermodel.HemfPicture;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Apache poi` not provides to get image dimensions from `Picture` of type `Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF`. The used `ImageUtils` method `getImageDimension` only is able to get dimensions from JPEG, PNG and DIB pictures,

But `apache poi` provides `org.apache.poi.hemf.usermodel.HemfPicture`. So

```
import org.apache.poi.hemf.usermodel.HemfPicture;
...
HemfPicture hemfPicture = new HemfPicture(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgData));
System.out.println(hemfPicture.getSize()); 
...
```

will print the correct dimensions.

But then it lacks a possibility to set those dimensions to the anchor. There is a method `scaleCell` in `ImageUtils` but not public accessible. So only way would be to copy source code of that method into your code.

Following complete example does that. It uses methos `scaleCell` having same code as in `ImageUtils`. The method `resizeHemfPicture` resizes the `Picture` to the `HemfPicture` dimension.

This is tested and works using `apache poi 5.0.0` and `Java 12`.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils;

import org.apache.poi.hemf.usermodel.HemfPicture;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class CreateExcelEMFPicture {
 
 public static double getRowHeightInPixels(Sheet sheet, int rowNum) {
  Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
  double points = (r == null) ? sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints() : r.getHeightInPoints();
  return Units.toEMU(points)/(double)Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL;
 }

 private static void scaleCell(final double targetSize,
                               final int startCell,
                               final int startD,
                               Consumer<Integer> endCell,
                               Consumer<Integer> endD,
                               final int hssfUnits,
                               Function<Integer,Number> nextSize) { 
  if (targetSize < 0) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("target size < 0");
  }

  int cellIdx = startCell;
  double dim, delta;
  for (double totalDim = 0, remDim;; cellIdx++, totalDim += remDim) {
   dim = nextSize.apply(cellIdx).doubleValue();
   remDim = dim;
   if (cellIdx == startCell) {
    if (hssfUnits > 0) {
     remDim *= 1 - startD/(double)hssfUnits;
    } else {
     remDim -= startD/(double)Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL;
    }
   }
   delta = targetSize - totalDim;
   if (delta < remDim) {
    break;
   }
  }

  double endDval;
  if (hssfUnits > 0) {
   endDval = delta/dim * (double)hssfUnits;
  } else {
   endDval = delta * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL;
  }
  if (cellIdx == startCell) {
   endDval += startD;
  }

  endCell.accept(cellIdx);
  endD.accept((int)Math.rint(endDval));
 }

 static void resizeHemfPicture(Picture picture, HemfPicture hemfPicture) {
  ClientAnchor anchor = picture.getClientAnchor();
  boolean isHSSF = (anchor instanceof HSSFClientAnchor);
  double height = hemfPicture.getSize().getHeight();
  double width = hemfPicture.getSize().getWidth();
  Sheet sheet = picture.getSheet();

  int WIDTH_UNITS = 1024;
  int HEIGHT_UNITS = 256;

  scaleCell(width, anchor.getCol1(), anchor.getDx1(), anchor::setCol2, anchor::setDx2, isHSSF ? WIDTH_UNITS : 0, sheet::getColumnWidthInPixels);
  scaleCell(height, anchor.getRow1(), anchor.getDy1(), anchor::setRow2, anchor::setDy2, isHSSF ? HEIGHT_UNITS : 0, (row) -> getRowHeightInPixels(sheet, row));

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelEMFPicture.xlsx";
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelEMFPicture.xls";

  CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

  //add picture data to this workbook.
  FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("./image.emf");
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
  int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF);
  is.close();

  HemfPicture hemfPicture = new HemfPicture(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
System.out.println(hemfPicture.getSize()); // returns correct dimension


  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

  anchor.setCol1(0);
  anchor.setRow1(4); 

  Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
System.out.println(picture.getImageDimension()); // 0, 0
System.out.println(ImageUtils.getDimensionFromAnchor(picture)); // 0, 0
  //picture.resize(); //will not work
  resizeHemfPicture(picture, hemfPicture);
System.out.println(ImageUtils.getDimensionFromAnchor(picture)); // correct dimension

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I am currently making use of `Java 11` and `Apache POI 5.0.0`. I am still unable to import `HemfPicture`. I guess I have some problem with my imports. My gradle imports: `implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.0.0'` and `implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.0.0'`. Do I need to make additional imports?

Comment: @dodobird: The `package org.apache.poi.hemf.usermodel` is in `poi-scratchpad-5.0.0.jar`. So dependency `name: 'poi-scratchpad', version: '5.0.0'` is needed too.